# GNU-CRYPTO: JCE cannot authenticate the provider GNU-CRYPTO

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, gnu

I am trying to use encryption algorithms from GNU-CRYPTO.
But whenever I try I get an: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider GNU-CRYPTO'

What is weird is the fact the I can use all hash functions from this package normally, but when I try to use ciphers I got those, for AES, DES, DESede...

Based on that I think the installation went fine. Also, when I use my code with other providers (BC,SUN), it works normally.

Could anyone help me with that.

```
    algorithm="DES";
    provider="GNU-CRYPTO";
    generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm); <-works
    generator.init(randGenerator);
    SecretKey key = generator.generateKey();

    cipherEncryption = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm, provider); <- stops here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the fact that that project was integrated into GNU classpath. That means that the last signed provider was for 1.4. Up to 1.5 you had to create signed versions of your libraries for each Java version, so one for 1.4 is probably not compatible with 1.5 and higher (check for instance the bouncy class library, which has separate downloads for each version of Java up to 1.5). Furthermore, the certificate may have expired.

Please use cryptographic libraries that are actually maintained. There should be no need for GNU crypto in the first place.

Comment: thanks you for this. I agree, it should not be used. I am not actually using the library for real projects. it is for a research project we are doing at the university.

Comment: To paraphrase Torvalts, that's one hell of an excuse :)